# Executing a function on session expiration in Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, session

I am developing a project in Codeigniter.
I am trying to use OneClickUpload to upload photo in a form with other inputs.

But I came across a problem using OneClickUpload to upload the image. Suppose, if a user uploads a photo but does not complete the form submission then the image remains stored in the server. I only want to store the image permanently if the user completes the form submission. 
I am using a session variable to save the image filename. I want to delete the image if the session expires i.e if the form is not submitted.

Is there a way to execute a function call(or a few lines of codes) to delete the image on session expiration in Codeigniter(preferably) or PHP.

Comment: Only option you have that run a cron job periodically to check session exist and then necessary action can be taken

Answer (score 0):

Referring [Manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html):

You can unset Session Variable like this:

```
$array_items = array('username' => '', 'email' => '');

$this->session->unset_userdata($array_items);
```

Comment: I am sorry. But that's not what I am looking for. I want to execute a function call when the session expires automatically.